# Media for a scaled high resolution

Tags: css, sass, responsive, scss-mixins

My team and I have an issue with our users who have high display resolutions (like 4k+, someone even has 5k).

We've decided to adapt our website to such resolutions, using media queries and rems.

```
/*!* Large screens ----------- *!*/
@media only screen and (min-width: $large-screen-min-width) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

/*!* HD screens ----------- *!*/
@media only screen and (min-width: $wqhd-screen-min-width) {
    html {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
}

/*!* Ultra-HD screens ----------- *!*/
@media only screen and (min-width: $ultra-hd-screen-min-width) {
    html {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
}
```

But then we found out, that almost all of them have some scales on the OS level. So everything they use is proportionally scaled, based on the settings they've set.

So our application looks pretty massive because of such scale.
Does anybody know any lifehacks for that? Because I guess not everyone uses such scales and also scales may differ from user to user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I never had such a scaling issue in mobile versions so far. But I have a guess, maybe the initial scale is not set in your HTML file. Just add the following line to your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: We use such meta viewport tag
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />